# Conditions of a piranha solution ocean

Tags: atmosphere, ocean, minerals

My super Earth has oceans of entirely [piranha solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution), that is, a mixture of sulfuric acid and hydrogen peroxide. The planet is very carbon rich and the crust is about 98% diamond and 2% quartz. The atmosphere is 80% carbon dioxide and 20% nitrogen. No life is present. Ignoring how such a planet came to be, how do these conditions interact?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more l. It is a little bit hard to figure out what you actually want @tungstn.

Comment: What's a piranha solution? How can no life be present if there are piranhas? What do they eat? Is it a case of autocorrect strikes again?

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. This is why it often called the auto-incorrect functionality... But no, I suspect that here it is really a [piranha solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution), that is, a mixture of concentrated sulfuric acid and hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Noting the sentence in the Wikipedia entry "It is this extremely reactive atomic oxygen species that allows piranha solution to dissolve elemental carbon," are you asking how long before the ocean dissolves the diamond crust, or at least the upper layers?  And kudos to the knowledge of @AlexP since I had never heard of it and assume auto-incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take the time to make a quick internet search for "dissolving diamond in piranha solution" you will find various videos that show you what happens.

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikQRcePrWVI) one which shows that, while piranha solution is extremely voracious, which I knew already from personal experience, having worked with it to clean surfaces during my PhD years, it does nothing appreciable to pure diamond (or at least, if it does anything, it's not within the sensitivity of the guy's scale).

You are just replicating the same experiment on a larger scale, saving our times by not trying with a sponge or an hot dog first (thanks!).

Moreover I am not so sure that piranha is stable over long times (sooner or later that atomic oxygen will combine and escape as O2), therefore if the kinetic of the dissolution is as slow as the video suggests, don't expect anything spectacular: the activity of the solution will be gone before the diamond.

Comment: After the activity dies, what are you left with in place of the piranha?

Comment: @tungstn sulfuric acid and water

Comment: I think not even sulfuric acid is very stable on the long-term. Considering that the planet is very carbonic, I believe some CO2 + SO2 + H2O equilibrial surface composition on the long-term.